# In jmeter want to add 2 parameter into body(Json).Record and replay is working,but want to pass 2 parameter in Json,so can pass values from CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I am working on one of the JMeter script and I have one question regarding an item. If I want add both the parameters into body data(Json format) then how can I do? When I record and play it is working fine but I want to modify the script by passing both parameters in Json format, so that I can pass the values from CSV file

Please see screenshot:

One of the value is Json format and other one is button. I know how to pass the multiple values but here one of the parameter is button.

I have passed both the parameters into body data and tried replaying the script but not able to do it with the button parameter. please help here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your screenshot is not visible.
2. JMeter doesn't know anything about [HTML buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_button.asp), it acts on [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) level

If you want to have the possibility to parameterize any data which is being sent by JMeter just put this data into the CSV file and replace the recorded hard-coded values with the [variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) defined in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) to see what are the JMeter Variables values and how does request look like. You will also have the possibility to compare the recorded and parameterized requests.